# Probability - balls and dice

Tags: probability

We have 3 cups with balls in them.

- First cup: 3black, 4white
- Second Cup: 2black, 6white
- Third cup: 5black, 1white

We throw a dice. If we throw:

- 1, we take one ball from first cup
- 2 or 3, we take one ball from second cup
- Otherwise we take one ball from third cup
- List item

What is probability of drawing a black ball?

After we draw a black ball, what is probability that we draw it from second cup?

For second question should just be 0.33 as it only depends on the dice, right? As for first question goes, I am totally lost. I tried as $3/7 + 2/8 + 5/6$ but that gives me more then 1 so it can't be right.

Comment: For the first, you are right to look at $\frac{3}{7},\frac{2}{8},\frac{5}{6}$ but you need to *condition* theses on the result of the die throw.  Multiply each by the probability of having chosen from that cup in the first place and *then* add.  For the second question no, it will not be $\frac{1}{3}$, nor will it be $0.33$ (*which is not equal to 1/3 I should point out*).  You will want to use Bayes' Theorem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem testing your knowledge of [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability)

For the first:

Let $B$ be the event that we took a black ball.

Let $X,Y,Z$ be the event that we took a ball from the first, second, or third cup respectively.  Note that $X,Y,Z$ create a partition of the sample space.

$Pr(B) = Pr(B\cap (X\cup Y\cup Z)) = Pr(B\cap X)+Pr(B\cap Y)+Pr(B\cap Z)$

$=Pr(X)Pr(B\mid X) + Pr(Y)Pr(B\mid Y)+Pr(Z)Pr(B\mid Z)$

$=\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{3}{7}+\frac{2}{6}\cdot \frac{2}{8}+\frac{3}{6}\cdot \frac{5}{6}$

---

For the second, apply [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

We wish to calculate $Pr(Y\mid B)$.  Using Bayes' Theorem we continue as:

$Pr(Y\mid B) = \dfrac{Pr(B\mid Y)Pr(Y)}{Pr(B)}$, each term of which we should know from the earlier problem part or from quick observations from the problem statement.

Comment: You throw a "die".  "Dice" is the plural of "die".

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote by $O_{k}$ the output of the die. Moreover, let us designate by $B$ the event "a black ball has been drawn". Therefore we are interested in the event
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(B) & = \textbf{P}(B\cap(O_{1}\cup O_{2}\cup O_{3}\cup O_{4}\cup O_{5}\cup O_{6}))\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{6}\textbf{P}(B\cap O_{k}) = \sum_{k=1}^{6}\textbf{P}(B|O_{k})\textbf{P}(O_{k})
\end{align*}

Therefore the sought result is expressed by
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(B) = \frac{1}{6}\left[\frac{C(3,1)}{C(7,1)} + 2\times\frac{C(2,1)}{C(8,1)} + 3\times\frac{C(5,1)}{C(6,1)}\right] = \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{3}{7} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{5}{2}\right) = \frac{4}{7}
\end{align*}

Once we have the probability $\textbf{P}(B)$, we are able to answer the second question. Precisely speaking, we are interested in the following probability

\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(O_{2}\cup O_{3}|B) & = \frac{\textbf{P}(O_{2}\cap B) + \textbf{P}(O_{3}\cap B)}{\textbf{P}(B)} = \frac{\textbf{P}(B|O_{2})\textbf{P}(O_{2}) + \textbf{P}(B|O_{3})\textbf{P}(O_{3})}{\textbf{P}(B)}\\
& = \frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{6}}{\displaystyle\frac{4}{7}} = \frac{1}{12}\times\frac{7}{4} = \frac{7}{48}
\end{align*}

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question you proceed as follows:
$$P(Choosing\ Black\ Ball)$$
$$=P(cup\ 1)P(Choosing\ Black\ Ball|cup\ 1)+P(cup\ 2)P(Choosing\ Black\ Ball|cup\ 2)+P(cup\ 3)P(Choosing\ Black\ Ball|cup\ 3)$$
$$=(1/6)(3/7)+(2/6)(2/8)+(3/6)(5/6)=4/7$$

---

For the second part you need $P(cup\ 2|Black\ Ball\ Chosen)=\frac{P(Black\ Ball\ Chosen|cup\ 2)P(cup\ 2)}{P(Black\ Ball\ Chosen)}=7/48$

Answer (score 0):

**We have 3 cups with balls in them.
First cup: 3black, 4white
Second Cup: 2black, 6white
Third cup: 5black, 1white
We throw a die. If we throw:
1, we take one ball from first cup**

The probability of a 1 is 1/6. Give that the probability of a black ball is 3/7.  The probability of rolling a 1 **and** drawing a black ball is (3/7)(1/6)= 1/14.

**2 or 3, we take one ball from second cup**

The probability of a 2 or 3 is 2/6= 1/3.  Given that the probability of a black ball is 2/8= 1/4.  The probability of rolling a 2 or a 3 **and** drawing a black ball is (1/4)(1/3)= 1/12.

**Otherwise we take one ball from third cup**

The probability we get anything other than a 1, 2,, or 3 (i.e. 4, 5, or 6) is 3/6= 1/2.  Given that the probability of a black ball is 5/6. The probability of rolling anything other than a 1, 2, or 3 [b]and[/b] drawing a black ball is (1/2)(5/6)= 5/12.

Over all, the probability of drawing a black ball is 1/14+ 1/12+ 5/12=  6/84+ 7/84+ 35/84= 43/84.